# sumy LexRankSummarizer() proper formatting of output text

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to get the output as string using `LexRankSummarizer` in `sumy` library.
I am using the following code (pretty straightforward)

```
parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(text,Tokenizer('english'))
summarizer = LexRankSummarizer()
sum_1 = summarizer(parser.document,10)
sum_lex=[]
for sent in sum_1:  
    sum_lex.append(sent)
```

using the above code I am getting an output which is in the form of `tuple`. Consider a summary as given below from a `text` as input

```
The Mahājanapadas were sixteen kingdoms or oligarchic republics that existed in ancient India from the sixth to fourth centuries BCE.
Two of them were most probably ganatantras (republics) and others had forms of monarchy.
```

Using the above code I am getting an output as

```
sum_lex = [<Sentence: The Mahājanapadas were sixteen kingdoms or oligarchic republics that existed in ancient India from the sixth to fourth centuries BCE.>,
 <Sentence: Two of them were most probably ganatantras (republics) and others had forms of monarchy.>]
```

However, if I use `print(sent)` I am getting proper output as given above. 
How to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing `sum_lex.append(sent)` with `sum_lex.append(str(sent))` should do.